# Set message in Laravel after redirecting guest to "/login" page

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-5.5

Sorry but I'm pretty new to Laravel, so I'll probably say some stupid things...

---

OK, I just created an authentication system using `php artisan make:auth`, and created a simple route with `auth` middleware:

```
Route::get("/test", "TestController@test")->middleware('auth');
```

When a *guest* enters the /test page, the auth system automatically redirect him to the /login page, which is OK.

However, I want to show the guest a message like "You have to login in order to view this page", so I've added this code to the `Auth/LoginController.php`:

```
public function showLoginForm()
{
     $intendedURL = \Session::get('url.intended');

     if($intendedURL)
         return view('auth.login')->with("message", "You must log in to continue");

     return view('auth.login');
}
```

Is it OK? Is it a good way to implement that? coz it looks pretty weird to me..

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is OK with the test if the user has an intended URL, one thing to keep in mind, this will impact all redirected users not just the ones from `/test`

But it is better to use message flushing on the session for this kind of messages without passing it in the view :

```
public function showLoginForm()
{
     $intendedURL = \Session::get('url.intended');

     if($intendedURL) {
         Session::flash('message', 'You must log in to continue');
      }

     return view('auth.login');
}
```

And in the view you will use `Session::has` method :

```
@if(Session::has('message'))
    <p class="alert alert-info">{{ Session::get('message') }}</p>
@endif
```

And add some CSS ;)

Comment: Actually, I want that any guest which is redirected to login page due to "auth", will see this message. The "test" page was just an example.
Anyway, the flash looks much better! :)

Comment: Yes it will do it, and that what's i said ;)